# RBTree implementation with generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement RBTree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree in Java with the help of generics as I will need this structure to be present in future part of project.

I have RBTree class :

```
public class RBTree<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

and RBNode class :

```
public class RBNode<T extends Comparable<T>>{ ...
 private T key; 
...}
```

Now here is the problem. I have a class Product, that has a ProductData object and so on. I need my tree to hold information about products expirations dates, and through the dates I need to be able to find the product.

I can now write my test code like this :

```
ProductDate p = new ProductDate(new ProductData("Jahoda", "12345678", new Date(), new Date(), 555, 10));
ProductDate r = new ProductDate(new ProductData("Mandarinka", "987654321", new Date(), new Date(), 111, 12));
ProductDate d = new ProductDate(new ProductData("Malina", "987654321", new Date(), new Date(), 222, 13));

RBTree<Date> produkty = new RBTree<Date>();
produkty.insert(p.getKey());
produkty.insert(r.getKey());
produkty.insert(d.getKey());
```

but here I will lost pointer to the given product. How to prevent this ?

I could provide my complete code to github if so.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by a pointer? There are no pointers in Java. 2. Why do you use new X(new X(...)) instead of just new X(...)?

Comment: well not default pointer, but reference, sorry for my bad ... I dont use X(new X(...)) but new PDate(new PData)), that is a difference. ProductDate is extended class from Product class, that has ProductData reference.

Comment: TreeMap from JDK is a Red Black tree implementation with generics.

Comment: Yea, @m3th0dman but this will not work for my teacher I belive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to use as a map, not as a set(that is, be able to get value by key), you can slightly change your `RBNode` class so that it stores both: key and value.
It can look like that:

```
public class RBNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    ...
}
```

Then instances of `ProductDate` should be used as keys and instances of `ProductData` as values if you want to get products for given dates.